# Products are not showed under catalog page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

My problem is when I add a product from catalog-product and associate it with a specific category. This product is not displayed on the category page.

For example: if I add a product and associate it with furniture section. When I click furniture page, there is no any product displayed on the furniture page.

I can't find a bug log online. But it is working on my localhost. Just no works for my live site.

Does anyone find the same problem before? And how can I fix it?

I turn on the debug mode and got this error:

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]
Access denied for user 'XXXXXX'@'%' to database 'XXXX'



CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ps_cat_restriction ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT DISTINCT cp.id_product, p.id_manufacturer, product_shop.condition, p.weight FROM ps_category c STRAIGHT_JOIN ps_category_product cp ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category AND c.nleft >= 35 AND c.nright <= 52 AND c.active = 1) STRAIGHT_JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = cp.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1) STRAIGHT_JOIN ps_product p ON (p.id_product=cp.id_product) WHERE product_shop.`active` = 1 AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant 'create temporary tables' privileges to your MySQL user.

Comment: How can I do it?  1. I have tried https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/626225-ps-1617-exception-due-to-missing-create-temporary-table-privileges/?tab=comments#comment-2633656. But it is still not working? 2. I also checked app/config/parameters.php, all the information is correct.

Comment: Use phpMyAdmin. You will find it in control panel of your hosting provider. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBF02LurEHg). If you can't use phpMyAdmin or are not allowed to edit user privileges, then you should consider moving your installation. Running a web store on poorly configured servers is really not recommended.

Comment: I have checked with my post provider: MySQL databases provisioned on our Cloud Hosting services do not allow customers to modify their user privileges. By default all new MySQL users have the following privileges, this cannot be modified.

SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW . Because my client , he purchase this host service, so I cant switch to cpanel right now. Getting frustrated, What else can I do?

Comment: I'm afraid, other than rewriting Prestashop there is not much you can do. You already lost more than a week on this issue. Just tell your client he has to find other hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to regenerate `.htaccess` file. Go to Prefereneces -> SEO and URLs, set Friendly URL to No and save. Then enable it back and save again.

Comment: Regenerating `.htaccess` could help if you copied it from your development environment with diferent server path. In that case, URLs would not be rewritten properly and possibly show empty categories. Anyway, updated answer shows it was a database issue.